# Hosting WMS layer using Geoserver, Tomcat, Amazon AWS?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, windows-8

My goal: provide clients with a password protected WMS url so they can access some of our GIS data.

Where I'm at so far:

OS: windows 8

I have a polygon shapefile created in QGIS I want to share as a WMS. This shapfile has been uploaded to a PostgreSQL database with the PostGIS extension enabled on the schema. I use PGadmin 4 to do this. The PostgreSQL database is stored on Amazon AWS.

Our client who is to receive the WMS layer, has been added as a read-only user role type. I can successfully log in to the database using the credentials I created for them.

I have installed tomcat apache with geoserver installed on it (127.x.x.x:82/geoserver). In geoserver (via tomcat web application manager) I create the WMS layer and style it. After publishing the layer as a WMS I can view it in QGIS.

However, on another PC, I can't access the WMS layer at all. So it seems the WMS is still hosted locally on the original PC. Even though I have tomcat installed and I'm not using localhost.

Now, I'm a bit of a noob with web hosting etc, so what should I do to gain access to this WMS layer on other PCs (online instead of local)?

Comment: 127 is localhost. The WMS client needs access to Tomcat/Geoserver, not Postgres on AWS (as Geoserver handles that for you). So, you either need to put Geoserver on AWS or some other client-facing url. There is a docker container for Geoserver. I don't know about AWS, but, I have set this up on GCP and it takes quite a bit of the pain away.

Comment: @JohnPowell thank for the comment john, 'you need to put Geoserver on AWS'- this. I can't find any documentation on doing this. It's all very complex for someone with minimal experience.

Comment: There are various links, [for example](https://cloudmaven.github.io/documentation/aws_geoserver.html), but, yes, setting up Geoserver can be a bit intimidating. This guide is for Linux, obviously, and I don't know what OS you are using, but you should be able to set up Geoserver on the same AWS virtual machine where you have installed Postgresql, at which point, it should be quite easy to add a new datasource.

Comment: @JohnPowell I'm using windows 8. That link is very specific to linux I think :(

Comment: OK, I see you have added the windows 8 tag. I have no experience outside of Linux any more, I'm afraid, but, the general principle is the same.

Comment: OK, I see you have added the windows 8 tag. I have no experience outside of Linux any more, I'm afraid, but, the general principle is the same. Just because you are running Windows locally, doesn't mean you can't run Linux on AWS, as installation is often a lot easier on Linux. But, again, I can see that this might be a bit daunting if you haven't used Linux and the command line before.